# React framer-motion EventListener problem

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

In a component, I made an animated success message :

```
    <motion.span
      ref={successRef}
      className="success"
      key="tab2Success"
      className={"success"}
      aria-live="assertive"
      whileInView="visible"
      initial="hidden"
      viewport={{ once: false }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.4 }}
      variants={{
        visible: {
          opacity: 1,
          height: "auto",
          marginBottom: 14,
        },
      }}
    >
      Création ajoutée avec succès !
    </motion.span>
```

If I remove this component from the DOM, I get :

```
Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'. TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at convertChangedValueTypes (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/dom/utils/unit-conversion.mjs?:85:34)
    at checkAndConvertChangedValueTypes (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/dom/utils/unit-conversion.mjs?:199:33)
    at unitConversion (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/dom/utils/unit-conversion.mjs?:227:11)
    at parseDomVariant (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/dom/utils/parse-dom-variant.mjs?:18:80)
    at HTMLVisualElement.makeTargetAnimatableFromInstance (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/dom/DOMVisualElement.mjs?:43:105)
    at HTMLVisualElement.makeTargetAnimatable (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/VisualElement.mjs?:329:21)
    at animateTarget (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/utils/animation.mjs?:82:105)
    at animateVisualElement (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/utils/animation.mjs?:36:21)
    at eval (webpack://brice/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/render/utils/animation-state.mjs?:24:151)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I tried to add `AnimatePresence initial={false}` around, unsuccessfully.

Has anyone ever had this problem ?

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? It's difficult to help without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think it's useless because if I change viewport={{ once: false }} to true, the problem is fixed. But if I need to deliver another success message, it is done without animation now.
For me the problem is that once:false will keep the element (listeners) in memory and if the element disappears from the dom, that creates the problem.

Comment: That may be happening because of the way the rest of your code is setup. It could be a hot reload thing, or something else, it's hard to know without knowing how the rest of your code is set up. It's working just fine in this [mockup I made](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/framer-motion-viewport-example-4w9q2r?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A22%2C39).